# Custom Profile User Throws Error When Subscribing To Platform Event

Tags: lightning-web-components, profile, platform-event, custom-profile

We have a lightning web component, that updates via the EMP API from an 'after insert' apex trigger. During testing we found that if we log in as a non-admin user (custom profile), the `onError` function from the `'lightning/empApi'` gets called with the following response:

```
{
channel: "/meta/subscribe",
clientId: "<id>",
error: "403:denied_by_security_policy:create_denied",
id: "264",
subscription: "event/<my_event>",
successful: false
}
```

The custom profile has `Read` and `Create` permission for the `<my_event>` event, has `API enabled` and `Read`, `Write`, `Create` and Edit permissions for the `Push Topic`.

(PS. The `subscribe` function resolves and returns with `replayId: -1`)

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you sure you granted permissions on the event object? The available permissions are `Read` and `Create`, there's no `Write`. You need to grant `Create`.

Comment: Yes,  sorry - I meant ``Read`` and ``Create``

Comment: Everything works as expected when signed in as an admin - doesn't that mean, the way we create runtime context is correct, and that the issue lies in the permissions (or something else) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We figured it out. We needed to change the `Deployment Status` of the Platform Event from `In Development` to `Deployed`. As the docs say:

> Deployment status lets you control who can access objects or platform events. We recommend that you select In Development while you set up your app or customization. That way, only admins (or users with the Customize Application permission) can access the object or platform event.
> When you’re ready to grant users access, change the status to Deployed.
>
> Later, if you change the object or platform event, select In Development again. Keep in mind that for custom or external objects, users can’t see custom tabs, related lists, or reports while objects are in development.

That is why it worked when signed in as an Admin, but not as a user with our Custom Profile

Comment: I am seeing the same error in my Aura Components. Permission Set grants Read/Create and the Platform Event is deployed.

Comment: I dont have a lot of experience in aura, so I can’t tell you anymore that what I wrote in the answer